# JQuery: replace string with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a string like this:

```
var stringA = "id=3&staffID=4&projectID=5";
```

how do i use regex to replace the value of staffID=4 to staffID=10?

any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to replace **staffID** use following **regexp** pattern,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xAT/43/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
str = "id=3&staffID=4&projectID=5";    
str = str.replace(/staffID=\d/g, "staffID=10");  
console.log(str);
```

#### Console Result

```
id=3&staffID=10&projectID=5
```

---

Same way you can change **id, staffID and projectID** using `/id=(\d+)&staffID=(\d+)+&projectID=(\d+)/g,` REGEXP **pattern**,

#### jQuery

```
str = "id=3&staffID=12&projectID=5";    
str = str.replace(/id=(\d+)&staffID=(\d+)+&projectID=(\d+)/g, "id=1&staffID=2&projectID=3");  
console.log(str);
```

#### Console Result

```
id=1&staffID=2&projectID=3
```

Check this <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xAT/45/)**</kbd> Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you Welcome i add more answer details

Comment: @user1153551 Your reply answers "how do I relace staffID=4 with staffID=10. This is not what David asked. There was some context around staffID, and given the question it should be assumed that he only wants to replace the staffID number when it appears in strings formed like "id=3&staffID=4&projectID=5"

Comment: that is what i want, i just need to replace the staffID, i dont care what is string infront or behind

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple regex you are looking for.

```
result = stringA.replace(/(id=\d+&staffID=)\d+(&projectID=\d+)/g, "$110$2");
```

Basically, the expression captures everything before the staffID into Group 1, and captures everything after the staffID into Group 2.

Then we replace the string with the Group 1 capture, concatenated with "10", concatenated with Group 2. That is the meaning of the "$110$2" replacement. The first number looks like 110, but the first 1 actually belongs to the $ ($1 means Group 1 in a replacement string).

Comment: @David You are welcome, just trying to answer according to the exact specs you gave us. :) Often, an imprecise regex will replace lots of strings that you don't want to replace. The devil is in the details.